# Error In DATABASE RESTORE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

```
private void restoreBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            if (databaseCmbBox.Text.CompareTo("") == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select A Database");
                return;
            }
            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            sql = "ALTER DATABASE " + databaseCmbBox.Text  +" SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate ; RESTORE DATABASE " +
            databaseCmbBox.Text + " FROM DISK = @PATH WITH REPLACE ; ALTER DATABASE " + databaseCmbBox.Text + " SET Multi_User ;";
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PATH", databaseRestorePath.Text);
            comm.CommandTimeout = 86400000;


            //sql = "Alter Database "+databaseCmbBox.Text+" Set SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
            //sql += "RESTORE Database " + databaseCmbBox.Text + " FROM DISK = '" + databaseRestorePath.Text + "' WITH REPLACE";
            comm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("Database Succesfully Restored");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
}
```

Please this code throws up this error,

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
>
> Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@PATH".
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Please what is the error with this code?

Comment: You adding parameter to comm and then creating new instance of comm!

Comment: Thank you so much...I really didnt see that error. It now works.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters should be added after main query string is defined.

```
 private void restoreBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (databaseCmbBox.Text.CompareTo("") == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select A Database");
                return;
            }
            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            sql = "ALTER DATABASE " + databaseCmbBox.Text  +" SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate ; RESTORE DATABASE " +
            databaseCmbBox.Text + " FROM DISK = @PATH WITH REPLACE ; ALTER DATABASE " + databaseCmbBox.Text + " SET Multi_User ;";
            comm.CommandTimeout = 86400000;


            //sql = "Alter Database "+databaseCmbBox.Text+" Set SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
            //sql += "RESTORE Database " + databaseCmbBox.Text + " FROM DISK = '" + databaseRestorePath.Text + "' WITH REPLACE";
            comm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PATH", databaseRestorePath.Text);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("Database Succesfully Restored");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is some confusion in your code. You use `comm` variable before you declare it (maybe it's also a mistake) but 
first

```
comm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
```

then

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PATH", databaseRestorePath.Text);
comm.CommandTimeout = 86400000;
```

second show the complete sqlcommand because

```
sql = "ALTER DATABASE " + databaseCmbBox.Text  +" SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate ; RESTORE DATABASE " +
```

isn't complete (ends with +)

third I suggest you to use SqlConnection inside using statment to be sure that it will always disposed

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{}
```